# Android - Observe doesn't work after navigation

Tags: android, navigation, state, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm developing an app right now and I'm facing one problem. I have simple login screen. I use Kotlin Flow to `emit` different states as `Loading`, `Success`, `Failure`. When state is `Loading` I want to navigate user to the loading screen. After that when state is `Success` I want to navigate user to the home screen. But other state than `Loading` is never called. It works when I remove navigation from `Loading` state. I suppose that after navigation to loading screen is `viewModel` cleared, I tried to log it but it doesn't write me message to the console.

```
private val viewModel: SignInViewModel by viewModels()


private fun observeSignIn() {
    viewModel.signIn.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        when (it) {
            is Status.Loading -> findNavController().navigate(R.id.loadingFragment)
            is Status.Failure -> {
                findNavController().navigateUp()
                showErrorSnackBar(sv_sign_in, it.message)
            }
            is Status.Success -> {
                findNavController().navigateUp()
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Maybe possible solution would be to use `viewModel` initialized by `navGraphViewModels` but it doesn't make sense to me because I use this loading screen for another screens...

Thanks for help :)

Comment: If this is your fragment and you move to another one when the status is Loading, the observer of this fragment stops because you navigate to another one. This fragment is send to the back.

Comment: Do you know any possible solution ?

Comment: As you said with the navGraphViewModel or a simple shared ViewModel between your fragments, you could put your observer in that ViewModel. But as far as I can see, you only want to show a loading screen and then move to your homeFragment. Therefore, maybe a DialogFragment that occupies the whole screen would be a better solution. You can show the DialogFragment for loading and when it's finished, you close the Dialog. With a DialogFragment, your observer of the Fragment stays active.